# Creating Footer HTML/CSS - Not Working

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to create a footer with 2 classes but for some reason they are not in the same line as each other. I've tried everything and I have no idea what the issue is. There is also additional white space below the footer. I want the footer to be a fixed height and keep the 2 elements on the same line (Copyright is centered and the icons are to the right). Can someone please help?

HTML:

```
    <footer>

    <div class="footer">

        <div class="copyright">Copyright</div>

        <div class="social-icons-footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>


</footer>
```

CSS:

```
   footer {
   clear: both;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: black;
          }

   footer .copyright {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 12px;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: white;
       }


   footer .social-icons-footer ul {
   list-style: none;
   float: right;
        }

   footer .social-icons-footer li {
   display: inline-block; 
        }

   .social-icons-footer ul a {
   color: white;
   margin: 14px;
   }

   .social-icons-footer ul a:hover {
   color: grey;
    }
```

Currently, it looks like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKBnA.png) - I want copyright to be in the center and the social icons to be to the right on the SAME line.

Comment: What is not in the same line? Can you put a jsfiddle link? or some kind of illustration to show what you have and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the purpose of the div `.footer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgzvrY

The changed settings are (in addition to the other settings):

```
footer {
   line-height: 60px;
 }
footer .social-icons-footer ul {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 12px;
   margin: 0;
 }
footer .social-icons-footer li {
   line-height: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: there's actually white space at the bottom, any idea why?

Comment: Probably because of the default body margin. Try to add `body, html: { margin: 0; }`

Comment: I added overflow: hidden; and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the div's to be inline

Add this code to your CSS `div.footer div{ display: inline;}`
And also remove `height:60px` from `footer` properties if not necessary..

Comment: I believe `display:inline-block` would be more appropriate, but otherwise ou are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline;` in your `.footer`

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can be ok for you I cut most unusefull css.

```css
.footer {width:100%;height:30px;line-height:30px;}
.copyright {width:50%;float:left;}
.social-icons-footer {width:50%;float:left;}
.social-icons-footer ul {text-align:right;margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;}
.social-icons-footer ul li {display:inline;padding:0px 5px;}
```

```html
<link media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<footer>

    <div class="footer">

        <div class="copyright">Copyright</div>

        <div class="social-icons-footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="font-size:30px"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>


</footer>
```